# Proxies, and how they can be traced

Tags: proxy

When you make an connection with a proxy and you do something shifty to a server, the people working the server could just call up all ISP's and then your ISP sees the last connection you made was to that proxy.

But then instead of that you go through a "double proxy" where in one proxy you connect to another proxy, and then you do something shifty. But still, the ISP can see you went through that proxy, and then communicate with the people working that proxy, then that proxy can say that you connected to the next proxy.

This means that if you are the only connected to a proxy, and the proxy are willing to give out information about any of there clients you're not that all safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exactly!**
 Using proxy to do nasty stuff isn't the most safe way to be anonymous, in some point you will have to trust them with your information.

There are proxy services that monitor all your conections and store them, so watch out when using this type of service, if you wanna know more about this, search for "Proxy Sniffing".

**Quick Note:** even if you use TSL/SSL in your connections using proxy you are vulnerable by 'Man-in-the-Middle' attack.

Comment: what is your reasoning that TLS is susceptible to MiTM attacks?